# jQuery tabs/validation submitting multiple forms

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms, jquery-ui

I'm using jQuery tabs and I'm using a form with each tab.  I have a submit button on the last form.  If validation for all the forms is successful, I want to be able to submit all the forms.

```
<s:div id="wrapper">
            <s:div id="maincontent">
                <s:div id="tabs">
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="#tabs-1" id="tab-1">Tab 1</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#tabs-2" id="tab-2">Tab 2</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#tabs-3" id="tab-3">Tab 3</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#tabs-4" id="tab-4">Tab 4</a></li>
                    </ul>
                    <s:div id="tabs-1">
                        <jsp:include page="/pages/tab1.jsp" />
                    </s:div>
                    <s:div id="tabs-2">
                        <jsp:include page="/pages/tab2.jsp" />
                    </s:div>
                    <s:div id="tabs-3">
                        <jsp:include page="/pages/tab3.jsp" />
                    </s:div>
                    <s:div id="tabs-4">
                        <jsp:include page="/pages/tab4.jsp" />
                    </s:div>
                </s:div>
            </s:div>
        </s:div>
```

I have the tabs and validation working fine.  Is there a way to submit all the forms when I press the submit button on the tab4 page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can attach javascript listener to the button for the 'click' event.

```
$('.button4').on('click', function() {
   $('.button').click();
});
```

This way you simulate click for the other buttons.
I am supposing that the other three buttons have HTML class button and the last button has class button4.
This is only for example.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I understand that, but again, I want to submit forms 1 - 3 as well.  Right now only tab4 is being submitted.

Comment: If these buttons are of type submit, this should work.
Another approach could be to give class for the other three forms and in the listener to submit them: `$('.form').submit();`

Comment: Oddly enough, that worked!  Weird, I added buttons to each screen, hid them and then used: `$("#btn1").click()` and it worked.  I also tried to do it without the button: '$("#tab1_form").submit()' and that didn't work.

Comment: Well, I was a little quick to +1 this.  The click only works for the first one.  The other two pages are skipped.  So, the answer is only partially corrct.

Comment: You are calling `$("#btn1").click()`. Are you calling `$("#btn2").click()` and `$("#btn3").click()` also?

Comment: Yes.  Those are the exact calls I'm making for each form.  Here is the code for the submit: `$('#btnTab1').click();   $('#btnTab2').click();   $('#btnTab3').click();    form.submit();`